# Injecting service account json as part of docker build

Tags: google-cloud-build

As part of the build process, I need to download some python packages from my private gcs bucket and install them as part of the Dockerfile. This could be done using a multi-stage builds like this one:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:alpine as gcloud
WORKDIR /packages
RUN gsutil cp gs://... /packages

FROM python:3.7.0
COPY --from=gcloud /packages .
```

but I have big problem with injecting service account from my local machine so that `gsutil` will be able to perform copy. I tried capturing content of service account json via `ARG` but it does not work with cloudbuild substitutions due to its json format:

```
gcloud builds submit . --substitutions _SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CONTENT="$(cat path_to_service_account.json)"
```

I also though about shared volumes between steps but it does not work with `docker build`. Any ideas how can I do this with cloudbuild?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to do this outside your Docker Build, and to leverage the Cloud Build built in authentication mechanism (through metadata server) to download the files.

In your cloud build steps

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ["cp", "gs://...", "./packages"]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/......', '.' ]
```

In your Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.0
COPY packages/* /packages/
.....
```

Simply grant the Cloud Build service account to have access to your bucket.

Comment: this is an option I have been considering but it is not better than having a Makefile since you need to do some cleanup of downloaded packages afterwards